# how can SnakeYaml deal with object inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, yaml, snakeyaml

I have yml file like this

```
 Staff:
 - name: chris
   type: intern
   hourlywage: 20
 - name: kevin
   type: full
   level: 9
```

I want to parse this yml file to get one `InternStaff` object and one `FullStaff` object. Is there any way to do this?

```
class Staff {
    String name;
}

class InternStaff extends Staff {
    String hourlyWage;
}
Class FullStaff extends Staff {
    String level;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Staff:
- !!InternStaff
  name: chris
  hourlyWage: 20
- !!FullStaff
  name: kevin
  level: 9
```

The part after the `!!` *must* be the qualified class name (including the class' package, if any).

If you want to keep your syntax (using `type: intern` instead of tags), refer to the [SnakeYaml docs for custom constructors and representers](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers). With some code, you can also make the tags more writer-friendly:

```
Staff:
- !intern
  name: chris
  hourlyWage: 20
- !full
  name: kevin
  level: 9
```

This requires registering a custom constructor for the `!intern` and `!full` tags.

Comment: What to do if those child classes have variables/parameters that are not standard strings, ints etc? Do you have to nest the `!!fully.qualified.class` for the required parameters?

Comment: @rocksNwaves You need annotations when the actual type cannot be derived from context. A POJO in the class fields would be fine without an explicit class name.

Comment: Hah! I had to google POJO, and I got to learn about JavaBean in the process. Thanks for the rabbit hole :) 

I've posted my comment as a full question here if you care to expand your comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68673671/how-to-instantiate-new-objects-with-object-parameters-using-yaml-config-file