# How to instantiate new objects with object parameters using YAML config file?

Tags: java, algorithm, config, snakeyaml

I am trying to use a config file to allow a user to choose a concrete clustering algorithm that implements some abstract class or interface. Each algorithm may have slightly different pre-requisite inputs. A small conceptual example:

- `KMedoids` just needs to have `k` set by the user.
- `SpectralClustering` also needs `k` but also needs several other things like `Enum`s representing the type of graph, and the type of laplacian to use in its internal calculations.

The things the two have in common are defined in an abstract class.

To make things more general, I made up a dummy example. Let's say I have a `Configuration` class that will be passed to an "engine" or "driver" of sorts to complete a job based on the instance of `Configuration` generated.

```
public class Configuration {

    private AbstractAlgorithm algo;
    private AbstractParameter param1;
    private ConcreteEnum.Enum1 param2;
    private ConcreteEnum.Enum2 param3;
   
    // getters and setters...
```

Then I have the classes

```
abstract class AbstractAlgorithm{
    AbstractParameter abstractParam;
    public void setParam(AbstractParam p) {
        this.abstractParam = p;
    }

    public RandomObject runAlgo(DataObject data);
}
```

and `ConcreteAlgorithm`:

```
public class ConcreteAlgorithm extends AbstractAlgorithm {

    ConcreteEnum.enum1 concreteParam1;
    ConcreteEnum.enum2 concreteParam2;

    public ConcreteAlgorithm(ConcreteParameter p1, ConcreteParameter p2) {
        this.concreteParam1 = p1;
        this.concreteParam2 = p2;
    }

    public abstract void runAlgo(DataObject data) {
        if (abstractParam == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        } else {
        // do calculations based on enums and abstractParam value
        }
    }
```

**My question then is:** how would the accompanying `.yaml` file look so that it could be parsed into an instantiated `Configuration` object that could be passed on to something that uses it?

Comment: This is quite a broad question, possibly too broad for SO. One general approach that comes to my mind would be that the concrete type of the algorithm must be encoded winthin the yaml configuration (e.g. through a field `type`), and each implementing class has a `type` that it "listens" to. The next step would be to get all concrete implementations of the abstract class and then, when reading a yaml, find the concrete implementation that belongs to the type.

Comment: @Turing85 Would you mind expanding that into an answer? It does seem like you have one in your head, but I'm having a hard time piecing together your comment into actionable advice (probably because I just learned YAML syntax last week).

Comment: This has less to do with YAML (the yaml part is adding a field `type: Foobar` to the yaml). Is has more to do with "figuring out which deserializer to call" based on aforementioned new field.

Comment: If you are familiar with json and how jackson handles things (see, e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379863/how-to-deserialize-interface-fields-using-jacksons-objectmapper)), then that is what I was thinking about.

Comment: If your question is about YAML, do tag with [tag:yaml], not only [tag:snakeyaml]. People familiar with multiple YAML implementations are more likely to follow the general tag than the tag of some specific implementation.

Comment: `sigma` must be on the same indentation level as `implementation` since it seems to be a sibling node. `implementation` cannot have both the scalar value `GaussianSimilarity` and a nested mapping. As for the other error, please ask a new question containing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Don't reshape your broad question to a specific question after you got a broad answer.

Comment: @flyx, I disagree that my initial question was broad. I provided actual code for a toy example, which is identical in function to what I'm doing with this new example which I actually care about. It seemed like you couldn't answer my question about multiple layers of nested object arguments based on the toy example, so I gave you something else which mimics it almost identically, but better illustrates the problem.

Comment: I shouldn't have focused on the broad vs specific question. The point is that StackOverflow doesn't work like a forum. You edited the whole content of your question which renders my answer very disconnected and therefore less useful to anyone ending up here. By doing this you place a burden on me to edit my answer, which I may or not may have time and knowledge for. And then you provided insufficient code to reproduce your problems (lots of referenced classes are missing).

Comment: @flyx That's fair. How should I proceed to make it right?

Comment: Since the `sigma` error was a mere typo and independent of the problem discussed, I think it would be best to undo your edit. StackOverflow has plenty of question about how to solve `mapping values are not allowed here` anyway, so we can have this question here to be about deserializing specialization/implementation classes.

Comment: Okay done. I'll accept your answer, but I think a small caveate that essentially says "And in the case your parameters have parameters, the yaml would look like this:..." because that question is the actual one I was searching for and could not find the answer too anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual with serialization, your classes should have a constructor with no arguments:

```java
abstract class AbstractAlgorithm {
    public AbstractParameter abstractParam;
}

public class ConcreteAlgorithm extends AbstractAlgorithm {
    public ConcreteEnum.Enum1 param1;
    public ConcreteEnum.Enum2 param2;
}
```

Whatever interface they have besides the fields is irrelevant to this question. I made the fields public since there is not really a point for them not to be when you're doing deserialization unless you want to process the given values in setters, in which case you would use setters.

Now with these types defined, loading will work as follows:

```java
Constructor constructor = new Constructor();
constructor.addTypeDescription(
    new TypeDescription(ConcreteAlgorithm.class, new Tag("!concrete")));
yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
AbstractAlgorithm = yaml.loadAs(someInput, AbstractAlgorithm.class);
```

and the YAML being loaded would look like this:

```yaml
--- !concrete
abstractParam: spam
param1: egg
param2: sausage
```

The `---` is the *directives end marker*, which starts the document's content and is optional. We use it here to make clear that the following tag applies to the root node of the document.

`!concrete` is that tag for the root node. Since we register it with SnakeYAML, it will lead to SnakeYAML constructing a ConcreteAlgorithm object from this file.

The following key-value pairs give values to each of the fields of a ConcreteAlgorithm, including the inherited field. SnakeYAML will process the field values depending on the nature of the used classes – `AbstractParameter` may want to have a nested mapping in the YAML file if it's a class. If `AbstractParameter` is another abstract class and has `ConcreteParameter` as implementation, you would do

```yaml
--- !concrete
abstractParam: !cp
  droggel: jug
param1: egg
param2: sausage
```

and register `!cp` as tag for `ConcreteParameter`. The nested mapping containing the key `droggel` will then generate an instance of `ConcreteParameter` and be assigned to the field `abstractParam`.

Since you can give tags on any level, you can nest fields with abstract class type anywhere in the structure you load your YAML into.

Comment: Thank you. I had just resigned myself to just reading the YAML as a map and making a bunch of `if` statements for object generation. Give me some time to work out a solution based on your answer and then I will accept it.

Comment: I've spent the past couple days going back to your many answers about snakeyaml and reading the docs. I think I've made progress, but I still seem to be getting tripped up by passing parameters that are classes with their own parameters. Perhaps this has to do with "registering a tag" which I don't fully understand. I have edited my question to include a simple but non-trivial working example. Maybe it will illustrate where my understanding is lacking.

Comment: I also played with instantiating the objects I want and then dumping them to see what the yaml would look like.

Comment: „registering a tag“ just means that you tell SnakeYaml „look I want to use `!foo` instead of `!!com.ara.jcluster.algorithms.SpectralClustering` because that's awfully long“.

Comment: Thank you, the issue was related to your comment on my question i.e. that `sigma` needed to be on the same level as implementation. If you would like to edit your answer accordingly, I will accept it.