# Build custom SnakeYAML Constructor to deserialize yaml file in a modular way

Tags: java, yaml, deserialization, snakeyaml

I would like to parse yaml files like the following using SnakeYAML:

```yaml
config:
  someBoolean: true
  someString: testing action descriptors
actions:
- print: Hello world
- print: Next action is add
- add:
    left: 25
    right: 17
- print: done
```

The target type for this document is `DocumentRoot`:

```java
public class DocumentRoot {
    public Config config;
    public List<Map<String, Object>> actions;
}

public class Config {
    public String someString;
    public boolean someBoolean;
}
```

So most of the document should be parsed by SnakeYAML directly into Java-Objects like the `config`-Attribute. However the `actions`-Attribute should be parsed in a modular way. Consider the following `ActionDescriptor`s:

```java
public interface ActionDescriptor<T> {
    String actionKey();

    Class<T> actionValueType();

    void runAction(T actionValue);
}

public class AddExpression {
    public int left;
    public int right;
}

private static List<ActionDescriptor<?>> createDescriptors() {
    return List.of(new ActionDescriptor<String>() {
        @Override
        public String actionKey() {
            return "print";
        }

        @Override
        public Class<String> actionValueType() {
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void runAction(String actionValue) {
            System.out.println(actionValue);
        }
    }, new ActionDescriptor<AddExpression>() {
        @Override
        public String actionKey() {
            return "add";
        }

        @Override
        public Class<AddExpression> actionValueType() {
            return AddExpression.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void runAction(AddExpression actionValue) {
            System.out.println("calculated: " + (actionValue.left + actionValue.right));
        }
    });
}
```

I would now like to use these `ActionDescriptor`s to use the `actions` attribute in the following way:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<ActionDescriptor<?>> descriptors = createDescriptors();
    DocumentRoot documentRoot = createYaml(descriptors).loadAs(new FileInputStream("data/input.yaml"),
            DocumentRoot.class);
    Map<String, ActionDescriptor<?>> descriptorMap = descriptors.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ActionDescriptor::actionKey, Function.identity()));
    if (documentRoot.config.someBoolean) {
        System.out.println(documentRoot.config.someString);
        for (Map<String, Object> actionMap : documentRoot.actions) {
            for (Entry<String, Object> entry : actionMap.entrySet()) {
                runAction(entry.getValue(), descriptorMap.get(entry.getKey()));
            }
        }
    }
}

private static <T> void runAction(Object actionValue, ActionDescriptor<T> descriptor) {
    Class<T> valueType = descriptor.actionValueType();
    if (valueType.isInstance(actionValue)) {
        descriptor.runAction(valueType.cast(actionValue));
    } else {
        System.out.println("expected '" + valueType + "' but got '" + actionValue.getClass() + "'");
    }
}
```

Currently I use the following method to create the `Yaml` instance of SnakeYAML:

```java
private static Yaml createYaml(List<ActionDescriptor<?>> descriptors) {
    Constructor constructor = new Constructor(DocumentRoot.class);
    for (ActionDescriptor<?> descriptor : descriptors) {
        // ???
        constructor.addTypeDescription(new TypeDescription(descriptor.actionValueType()));
    }
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(constructor);
    yaml.setBeanAccess(BeanAccess.FIELD);
    return yaml;
}
```

When running the program I get the following output:

> ```
> testing action descriptors
> Hello world
> Next action is add
> expected 'class animatex.so.AddExpression' but got 'class java.util.LinkedHashMap'
> done
> ```

But I would like to have the following one:

> ```
> testing action descriptors
> Hello world
> Next action is add
> calculated: 42
> done
> ```

Clearly SnakeYAML does not use the desired types for the deserialization of the action values. So I need to somehow tell SnakeYaml at the location `???` that if it deserializes a value in a map entry (whose map is an entry in the list in the attribute `actions`) then it should use the type `descriptor.actionValueType()` if the respective key of the map entry is `descriptor.actionKey()`.

I already tried several things using `TypeDescriptor`s, `Constructor`s and `Construct`s and digged into the Code of SnakeYaml, but I simply do not really understand how it works so I am unable to build a working constructor for this use case.

If it helps, I can also extend the `ActionDescriptor` interface to provide a `TypeDescriptor`, `Constructor`, `Construct` ...

I would really like to avoid adding tags to the yaml file, but if there is no other solution I might bite that bullet.

My question is: How can I build such a `Constructor`? Looking forward to your comments and answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to avoid nested generics. To do so, we can adjust the class `DocumentRoot` as follows:

```java
public class DocumentRoot {
    public Config config;
    public List<ActionMap> actions;
}

public class ActionMap {
    private final Map<String, Object> actions;

    public ActionMap(Map<String, Object> actions) {
        this.actions = actions;
    }
}
```

We wrapped the map into an object of type `ActionMap`. Now we need to tell SnakeYAML how to parse a `MappingNode` (anything that looks like a map in the yaml file) into an object of type `ActionMap`. I found a way to extend the class `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor` in such a way that this is easily possible:

```java
public class MyConstructor extends Constructor {
    public MyConstructor(Class<?> rootClass,
            Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<Function<Node, Object>, MappingNode, Object>> mappingNodeConstructors,
            Map<Class<?>, BiFunction<Function<Node, Object>, SequenceNode, Object>> sequenceNodeConstructors) {
        super(rootClass);
        this.yamlClassConstructors.put(NodeId.mapping, new ConstructMapping() {
            @Override
            public Object construct(Node node) {
                for (Entry<Class<?>, BiFunction<Function<Node, Object>, MappingNode, Object>> entry : mappingNodeConstructors
                        .entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(node.getType())) {
                        if (node.isTwoStepsConstruction()) {
                            throw new YAMLException("Unexpected 2nd step. Node: " + node);
                        } else {
                            return entry.getValue().apply(MyConstructor.this::constructObject, (MappingNode) node);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return super.construct(node);
            }

            @Override
            public void construct2ndStep(Node node, Object object) {
                throw new YAMLException("Unexpected 2nd step. Node: " + node);
            }
        });
        this.yamlClassConstructors.put(NodeId.sequence, new ConstructSequence() {
            @Override
            public Object construct(Node node) {
                for (Entry<Class<?>, BiFunction<Function<Node, Object>, SequenceNode, Object>> entry : sequenceNodeConstructors
                        .entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().isAssignableFrom(node.getType())) {
                        if (node.isTwoStepsConstruction()) {
                            throw new YAMLException("Unexpected 2nd step. Node: " + node);
                        } else {
                            return entry.getValue().apply(MyConstructor.this::constructObject, (SequenceNode) node);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return super.construct(node);
            }

            @Override
            public void construct2ndStep(Node node, Object object) {
                throw new YAMLException("Unexpected 2nd step. Node: " + node);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that we completely ignore SnakeYAML's so-called 2nd step which, to my understanding, is only used for yaml files which use references. Since I don't need this feature I ignored it. Also note that we don't need to handle `SequenceNode`s for this example, but it might still be useful to have for some people.

SnakeYAML's parsing works as follows:

1. Parse the document into `Node`-Objects
2. Tag `Node`-Objects with a target type
3. Converts `Node`-Objects to desired target type

For step three, SnakeYAML uses the `construct`-method of the `ConstructMapping` to convert a `MappingNode` (anything that looks like a map in the yaml file) into its target type. Similarly it uses the `construct`-method of the `SequenceMapping` to convert a `SequenceNode` (anything that looks like a list in the yaml file) into its target type.

Now we can use an instance of `MyConstructor` to tell SnakeYAML how to parse a `MappingNode` into an `ActionMap`:

```java
private static Yaml createYaml(List<ActionDescriptor<?>> descriptors) {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml(createConstructor(descriptors));
    yaml.setBeanAccess(BeanAccess.FIELD);
    return yaml;
}

private static Constructor createConstructor(List<ActionDescriptor<?>> descriptors) {
    Map<String, ActionDescriptor<?>> descriptorMap = descriptors.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ActionDescriptor::actionKey, Function.identity()));
    Constructor result = new MyConstructor(DocumentRoot.class, Map.of(ActionMap.class, (constructor, mnode) -> {
        Map<String, Object> actionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (NodeTuple entry : mnode.getValue()) {
            Node actionKeyNode = entry.getKeyNode();
            Node actionValueNode = entry.getValueNode();
/* (1) */   String actionKey = (String) constructor.apply(actionKeyNode);
/* (2) */   Class<?> actionValueType = descriptorMap.get(actionKey).actionValueType();
/* (3) */   actionValueNode.setType(actionValueType);
/* (4) */   Object actionValue = constructor.apply(actionValueNode);
/* (5) */   actionMap.put(actionKey, actionValue);
        }
        return new ActionMap(actionMap);
    }), Map.of());
    TypeDescription typeDescription = new TypeDescription(DocumentRoot.class);
    typeDescription.addPropertyParameters("actions", ActionMap.class);
    result.addTypeDescription(typeDescription);
    return result;
}
```

Here, we tell `MyConstructor` that it can convert a `MappingNode` into an `ActionMap` by using the given lambda. This lambda iterates all entries of the `MappingNode`. For each entry it (1) extracts the `actionKey`, (2) determines the `actionValueType` based on the `actionKey`, (3) tags the value `Node` of the entry with the `actionValueType`, (4) calls back into SnakeYAML to convert the value `Node` into the `actionValueType` and (5) creates a new entry in the `actionMap` for the determined `actionKey` and `actionValue`. Finally it wraps the `actionMap` into an `ActionMap`.

Finally the method `createConstructor` creates a `TypeDescriptor` to tell SnakeYAML that the generic type parameter of the `actions` attribute of the class `DocumentRoot` is `ActionMap`. This is necessary due to Java's type erasure.

I adjusted the code to actually run the actions as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<ActionDescriptor<?>> descriptors = createDescriptors();
    DocumentRoot documentRoot = createYaml(descriptors).loadAs(new FileInputStream("data/input.yaml"),
            DocumentRoot.class);
    if (documentRoot.config.someBoolean) {
        System.out.println(documentRoot.config.someString);
        for (ActionMap actionMap : documentRoot.actions) {
            for (ActionDescriptor<?> descriptor : descriptors) {
                runAction(actionMap, descriptor);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static <T> void runAction(ActionMap actionMap, ActionDescriptor<T> descriptor) {
    actionMap.getActionValue(descriptor).ifPresent(v -> descriptor.runAction(v));
}
```

Where `getActionValue` is a method in the class `ActionMap`:

```java
public <T> Optional<T> getActionValue(ActionDescriptor<T> descriptor) {
    if (actions.containsKey(descriptor.actionKey())) {
        Object actionValue = actions.get(descriptor.actionKey());
        Class<T> valueType = descriptor.actionValueType();
        if (valueType.isInstance(actionValue)) {
            return Optional.of(valueType.cast(actionValue));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("expected '" + valueType + "' but got '" + actionValue.getClass() + "'");
        }
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

---

As @flyx pointed out in their answer, this approach implements „poor man's tags“ instead of using the existing tagging feature of yaml and SnakeYAML. Thus before using this approach think about using the existing tagging feature in yaml and SnakeYAML.

However, this approach is just what I want and I might not be the only one, for example ansible seems to use a similar yaml layout for its task lists. In my actual use case it also makes sense to have multiple actions in a single list entry which is not directly possible with yaml tags.

In a real world application one probably wants to add better error handling and some class that is more specialized than the type `BiFunction<Function<Node, Object>, MappingNode, Object>>`. I omitted these refinements to prevent this answer from becoming even longer.

Answer (score 1):

You are fighting YAML itself here. YAML defines that you should use *tags* to denote the type of a node if you need to do so explicitly. It would look like this:

```yaml
config:
  someBoolean: true
  someString: testing action descriptors
actions:
- !print Hello world
- !print Next action is add
- !add
  left: 25
  right: 17
- !print done
```

This would be fairly simple to load via SnakeYAML, you can even have `DocumentRoot.actions` to be of type `List<ActionDescriptor<?>>` directly.

Your approach tries to do „poor man's tags“ instead of using the existing feature. SnakeYAML's interface is difficult to use in that case because it expects you to use actual tags to do something like this.

You tell YAML that the value inside of an `actions` mapping is an `Object`. If you do this, YAML will construct generic collection types like `LinkedHashMap` since you do not give it any more specifics, and that is the cause for your error. To overcome this, you would have to manually construct the inner structure from the general `LinkedHashMap` value SnakeYAML yields.

I strongly suggest to use tags instead. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68673671/347964) shows how to define custom tags for classes implementing an abstract interface. You also need to set the actual type of the `actions` content as described in [the SnakeYAML docs](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-type-safe-collections).

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your answer. I looked into tagging for yaml, but it is not what I want. Thus I figured it out by myself and self-answered the question. Your answer might still be valuable for other users!